# knockout.js - Looping over one array in a hash of arrays

Tags: knockout.js

My rails app is sending a large JSON structure to my page, which contains an element like this:

```
"nutrient_contributions": {
  "Vitamin K": [
    [
      "Broccoli (raw)",
      "92.46 mcg"
    ],
    [
      "ginger - ground",
      "0.04 mcg"
    ]
  ],
  "Vitamin B-6": [
    [
      "pepper - cayenne",
      "0.13 mg"
    ],
    [
      "ginger - ground",
      "0.03 mg"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Using knockout, I want to turn ONLY ONE of those hash elements into an HTML table.  In the below example, the th with `'text: display_nutrient'` is rendering as `Vitamin B-6`; am I wrong in thinking I should be able to use display_nutrient as a hash key?

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th{colspan: 2, data: { bind: 'text: display_nutrient' }}
    %tr
      %th Ingredient Name 
      %th Nutrient Value
  %tbody{data: { bind: 'foreach: $root.recipe().nutrient_contributions()[display_nutrient]()' }}
    %tr
      %td{data: { bind: 'text: shift()' }}
      %td{data: { bind: 'text: shift()' }}
```

Using the javascript console, I can see that my data is being loaded not as simple JSON, but is being turned into an object.

```
> window.my_recipe_view_model.recipe().nutrient_contributions()
    Object {Vitam B-6: function, Vitamin K: function…}
> window.my_recipe_view_model.recipe().nutrient_contributions()['Vitamin K']()
  [
      Array[2]
      0: "Broccoli (raw)"
      1: "92.46 mcg"
      length: 2
      __proto__: Array[0]
      , 
      Array[2]
      0: "ginger - ground"
      1: "0.04 mcg"
      length: 2
      __proto__: Array[0]
  ]
```

So, the million dollar question is-  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your display_nutrient is a `ko.observable` you need to write: `'foreach: $root.recipe().nutrient_contributions()[display_nutrient()]()'` note the additional `()` after `display_nutrient`. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yKeEo

Comment: That was it!  I knew it was something stupid.   If you had added this as an answer instead of a comment, I'd mark it as Correct....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `display_nutrient` property is a `ko.observable` then you need to unwrap it inside your `foreach` binding expression with calling it as a function:

```
data-bind='foreach: $root.recipe().nutrient_contributions()[display_nutrient()]()'
```

Note the `()` after `display_nutrient`.

Demo: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yKeEo)